# Flutter in_app_purchase plugin

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

Good day! I have a few questions regarding the in_app_purchase plugin (^0.5.2).

1. When and why should I use the `.consumePurchase()` method?
2. Is it ok to call `.consumePurchase()` on a non consumable product?
3. When and why should I use the `.completePurchase()` method?
4. Why do I need to call `.completePurchase()` every time I start the app (if I've already completed it when purchased)?

Answer (score 0):

If i can suggest you [purchases_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter) package, saved my life, a lot easier to use and has full documentation on there site.
You get a good support and a good community support. Works like a charm and passed Apple Interview on my app.